# Cross-domain hash change communication

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain, hashchange

Please consider the following two domains: domain1.com and domain2.

From domain1 I open an iframe that points to domain2.

Now, I want these guys to communicate with each other, which I've successfully accomplished by applying hash change event listeners on both domains.

That way, the hash in the parent window (domain1) will trigger if domain2 calls parent.location with a new hash. Also, the hash change event triggers in the iframe if I from the parent changes its src attribute to a new hash.

This works great!

Here comes the trouble:

The back and forward functionality in the browser gets messed up. Simply put, by creating two hash instances, the browser back button has to be clicked twice to get the parent hash to change since it has to cycle through the iframe's hash first.

How can I communicate with a cross-domain iframe 2-way without screwing up the history object?

Thanks!

Comment: One possible (UGLY!) solution I've come to think of: I could append a script on domain1 that points to domain2 like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain2.com/#whatever=hash&i=want&to=parse"></script>. This JS file will then set a cookie that another JS file on domain2 will listen for changes to. When the cookie changes, something has been changed and you act accordingly. Any thoughts on this approach?

Comment: This might not work though. Will require a request each time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net), it's a javascript library that does all the hard work for you, enabling you to do cross-domain communication and RPC in all browsers, including IE6.

This will not use the HashTransport for any of the current browsers (not even IE6), and so will not change the history.

You will not find anything better..

You can read about some of its inner workings in this [Script Junkie article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/scriptjunkie/ff800814(en-us).aspx), or go straight to the [readme at github](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM/#readme)

Comment: Hi Sean. Wow, really impressive work. I'm implementing it now! Will let you know how it works out for me. Thanks so far, buddy

Comment: By the way, what browsers will utilize the HashTransport? Need to block them since it will screw with my existing hash implementation for bookmarkability and navigation.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. There's a list in the readme of all the 'grade A' browsers supported, these will not use the HashTransport.

Comment: Ah, okay. I've implemented it now. Thanks again! Works like a charm.

Comment: Cool :) Did you have any issues understanding how to use it? Was the readme sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Another technique for crossdomain communications is (ab)using `window.name`. It requires an iframe to originally have a same-domain src initially after which you move to another domain that sets the window.name and then steps back to the original source (step back in history). The idea is that the `window.name` does not change unless it's explicitly set, this means you can transfer `window.name` data cross domain.

This technique is described in more detail on:
- http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/10/11/leveraging-window.name-transport-for-secure-and-efficient-cross-domain-communications.aspx
- http://jectbd.com/?p=611

Be sure to choose the implementation that avoids clicking sounds in IE.

Unfortunatly, it still messes around with your history, but it does a step forward and then backwards to the history point it was at. A big benefit though, is that you don't have to parse and encode URI strings, but can use JSON right away.

*[Using JSON lib for example](http://www.json.org/)*

```
// access window.name from parent frame
// note: only when iframe stepped back to same domain.
var data = JSON.parse( iframe.contentWindow.name );

// set child frame name
// note: only when iframe stepped back to same domain.
iframe.contentWindow.name = JSON.stringify( {
    foo : "bar"
} ); // to JSON string

// set own name ( child frame )
window.name = JSON.stringify( {
    foo : "bar"
} ); // to JSON string
```

The cookie technique is viable as well, for both techniques you need to perform ajax requests in the target iframe if you want to avoid history changes but still require http request.
so:

1. Send data to iframe x (using cookie or window.name technique)
2. Catch data with poller in iframe x
3. Perform ajax requests in iframe x.
4. Send data back to iframe y (using cookie or window.name technique)
5. Catch data with poller in iframe y
6. Do the hokey pokey.

Any page refresh (httprequest) or url change will update the history (except for old or all IE versions), so more code is required alas.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! Very appreciated. However, are you sure this works cross-domain? When I try to access the window.name from the iframe I get: Error: Permission denied for <http://domain1.com> to get property Window.name from <http://domain2.com>.

Comment: Looking into it, which browser did you use?

Comment: Firefox 3.6.12 on macosx. Happens in Chrome 7 as well: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://domain1.com from frame with URL http://domain2.com. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: My appologies, there's a bit more to the technique. See the article links and updated my awnser. In any case, any technique will feel like a hack =(

Comment: No worries. According to the Script Junkie article Sean posted window.name won't be working in newer browser versions. I'll go with the easyXDM framework. Thank you so much for your time and help!