# IFrame call parent function

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

is it possible for an iframe to call a parent's function, **even if they are not in the same domain**?
My actual approach lifts a security error when they are not on the same domain:

```
<script>
function test()
{ alert('wow');
}
</script>
<iframe src="...."></iframe>
```

And inside the iframe i would do this:

```
<script> 
function fin() 
{ top.test(); } 
</script>
```

Many thanks :)

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122422/cross-domain-hash-change-communication

Answer (score 4):

You can't call the function directly (due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but you can use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) (as described in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460200/can-cross-origin-resource-sharing-headers-authorize-x-domain-iframe-access)) and have an event listener call that function in response.

You're going to be somewhat [out of luck](http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage) if you need to support Internet Explorer 7 and lower.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. The same origin policy forbids this.

Comment: Thats not true. You can use postMessage. We do in our applications. Because like if you're using ie7 you can get lost.

Comment: That's not the same as „calling a function in an iframe,“ sorry :)

Comment: It can be. You can use postMessage to send a message which then causes your listener to call the function. It's not identical but it accomplishes the same goal.